# Why does Java Spec recommend using int... for the formal parameter and int[] for the functional interface?

Tags: java, lambda, jls

*JLS12, 15.27.1  Lambda Parameters* says:

> No distinction is made between the following lambda parameter lists:
>
> ```java
> (int... x) -> BODY
> (int[] x) -> BODY
> ```
>
> Either can be used, whether the functional interface's abstract method is fixed arity or variable arity. (This is consistent with the rules for method overriding.) Since lambda expressions are never directly invoked, *using `int...` for the formal parameter where the functional interface uses `int[]` can have no impact on the surrounding program*. In a lambda body, a variable arity parameter is treated just like an array-typed parameter.

And I want to ask what leads to the conclusion emphasized above? What is the *have no impact on the surrounding program* exactly means?

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is.  The `int...` notation is just syntactic sugar for an `int[]` parameter, allowing a "naked" variable-length list in the call instead of having to make the array yourself.

Comment: "no impact" I think mean that it just doesn't matter.  Both are treated identically in every way.  There's no performance impact, and there's no subtleties of the language that might cause a compilation error.

Comment: @markspace good point about "it does not matter"; the other question is what "Since lambda expressions are never directly invoked..." supposed to mean, I guess; and would that result in a different conclusion if they could be directly invoked (again, whatever that means )

Comment: @markspace I _guess_ they mean that you can't call any methods on it directly, like `(x-> x * x).hashCode()` for example; but still not clear how that would change the sentence even if it would be possible.

Comment: There is no such recommendation. Instead there is the mere statement of fact that 'either can be used'.

Comment: I've tried `int[]` for the functional interface and neither `int...` nor `int[]` for the formal parameter can I call this lambda like `test.accept(1, 2, 3)` for `BiConsumer<Integer, int[]> test = (Integer a, int... list) -> BODY`. And I agree that the "since" part is important, but yet still I don't know why it is.